# Disable null reference warning when I've checked for nulls

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, resharper, code-analysis

In the following code, if `cmd` has been initialized, then I'll make to sure to close any open connections before throwing an exception. However, even after I check that `cmd` is not null, I still get a possible null reference warning in subsequent lines of code.

```vb
Dim cmd As SqlCommand
Try
    'Do some Stuff
Catch ex As Exception
    If cmd IsNot Nothing AndAlso
       cmd.Connection IsNot Nothing AndAlso              '<- null cmd warning 
       cmd.Connection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then  '<- null cmd warning 
        cmd.Connection.Close()                           '<- null cmd warning 
    End If
    Throw
End Try
```

I get the two following warnings (possibly one from Resharper & one from Visual Studio):

> - Variable 'x' might not be initialized before accessing.  A null reference exception could occur at runtime.
> - BC42104: Variable 'x' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime.

According to the [Visual Studio Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3fdk625a.aspx):

> An application has at least one possible path through its code that reads a variable before any value is assigned to it.

But I don't think there is even one possible path through the code where the variable would be used without being initialized.

- Have I made some error or is this a bug?
- Is there a way to disable this warning from coming up?

Here's a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

This is different from many similar questions already asked here, like [Prevent Resharper “Possible Null Reference Exception” warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5172674/1366033) because I'm not trying to allow for a NullableType, but instead have already guaranteed that my variable is not null.

---

### Update:

Follow up question: Why?

Whether my object is never initialized or initialized to `Nothing`, in both cases `cmd IsNot Nothing` should resolve to `False`, so anything after the `AndAlso` should never be executed.

```vb
Dim cmd1 As SqlCommand
Console.Write(cmd1 IsNot Nothing) 'False

Dim cmd2 As SqlCommand = Nothing
Console.Write(cmd2 IsNot Nothing) 'False
```

Maybe the compiler just doesn't have a good way of guaranteeing this at compile time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is not that your value is null, the problem is that your object is not initialized at all. For example:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> empty;

        if (empty != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("no");
        }
    }
```

**Will not compile**, because `empty` has no value. If I change the code to:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> empty = null;

        if (empty != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("no");
        }
    }
```

It'll work, because my list now has a value, it's null, but it still exists.

EDIT: Sorry I used C# instead of VB, that's because that editor I have handy, but the code is correct. 
You initialize your variables every time and you'll not gonna get the error.

Comment: I don't see a downvote and I definitely didn't downvote you.  Perhaps someone upvoted and then retracted?  If you click on the score it will give you the breakdown of upvotes vs. downvotes.

Comment: Am sorry it is my downvote. and it's my upvote too :) Reason I downvoted because I know this won't compile in c# but strange that vb.net compiler just gives a warning. It compiles fine. I was under the impression that this won't compile in vb.net too intuitively; but then op says he gets a warning. good to know new thing. btw good answer :)

Answer (score 3):

If you put

```
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = Nothing
```

It should be ok..

Comment: I guess my follow up question is why?  Whether my object is not initialized or initialized to nothing, in both cases `cmd IsNot Nothing` should resolve to `False`, so anything after the `AndAlso` should never be executed.

Comment: I'm sure it's just generic behavior. If you took a date variable for example, that would not be nothing. Try running this:            Dim dt As Date : If IsNothing(dt) Then  Throw New Exception("Hello"). It's just trying to encourage you to always put a value into a variable, even if it's nothing because some variables if not initialised will not resolve to nothing :)